# Google search in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to search in google the value of x. It doesn't work with this code:

```
function func2(){
            var x = document.getElementById("gsearch").innerHTML;
            window.open("http://www.google.com/#q="+x,"_self");
        }
```

Comment: If gsearch is an input, you should use getElementById("gsearch").value instead of .innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting in a old question.
You can do that with the `<form>` tag.

```
<form action="https://www.google.com/search">
  <input type="search" name="q">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to open a new tab with a Google Search?

Something like:

```
function func2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("gsearch").value;
  OpenInNewTab("http://www.google.com/custom?q=" + x);
}

function OpenInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OCJPubbqKlRZHandkwg8?p=preview)

[New Tab via JS Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)